# Vue 3 + Auth0 - How to directly link to login page using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, auth0

I feel this should be easy but for some reason, it doesn't work as intended.

Currently the Auth0 login page only works if I have a login button that execute the `loginWithRedirect()` function.

But how do you get the login page to appear if someone were to go directly to `https://example.com/login`?

I thought the best way to do this along with everything else auth related would be via the router with something like this

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue"

const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0()

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        children: [
            {
                path: '/login',
                beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                    loginWithRedirect()
                }
            },
        ],
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
})

export default router
```

But this leads to `'loginWithRedirect' of 'useAuth0(...)' as it is undefined`

This also then begs the question, can you not add route guards into the router file when using Auth0?